# how to show which thread is being rejected to Enter in critical section by use of semaphore

Tags: multithreading, semaphore

This Code is pretty fine to demonstrate Critical Section problem, but i've TWO   QUERIES about the code,

1. How to show WHICH THREAD is being rejected to Enter in Critical Section ?
2. thread 'A', 'B', 'C' are created in listed order. HOW can i start them at single time ?

Here is the code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void *doSomething1();
void *doSomething2();
void *doSomething3();

sem_t sem;

int main() {
    // initialize semaphore to 2
    sem_init(&sem, 1, 2);

    pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3;

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &doSomething1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &doSomething2, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, &doSomething3, NULL);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);

    return 0;
}

void doSomething(char c) {
    int i, time;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (sem_wait(&sem) == 0) {
            // generate random amount of time (< 7 seconds)
            time = (int) ((double) rand() / RAND_MAX * 7 );
            printf("#thread %c GOT-ACCESS to CRITICAL SESSION for %d sec\n", c, time);
            sleep(time);
            printf("\t->thread %c RELEASED CRITICAL SESSION\n",c);
            sem_post(&sem);
        }
    else    
        printf("thread %c FAILED TO ENTER CRITICAL SECTION",c);
    }
}

void *doSomething1() {
    // thread A
    doSomething('A');    return 0;
}

void *doSomething2() {
    // thread B
    doSomething('B');    return 0;
}

void *doSomething3() {
    // thread C
    doSomething('C');    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a thread to be "rejected" from entering you would have to replace `sem_wait()`, which is a blocking call with `sem_trywait()`or `sem_timedwait()`although then they might not ever enter the critical section (without some more modifications to the code). But since you only want to see when a thread is denied entering the section this should be sufficient. (for more information on these methods visit the man page http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_wait ).

As for the second the question the answer is that you actually cannot start all threads at once, they have to start in some sort of order. However you can (if you want) start multiple threads and use a semaphore to block them until all threads are ready and then release them all at once, which is as close as you can get to starting them at once.

Comment: As I said, just replace the line `if (sem_wait(&sem) == 0) {`with `if (sem_trywait(&sem) == 0) {`